# bootstrap modal not showing with jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to open modal on click action of the last column action but I cannot view the modal on click and my jquery is not working properly in my laravel application , any ideas why ?, Any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

 {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />--}}
{{--    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">--}}
    <linK href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="margin-top: 30px;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="app-content content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-header row">
            </div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <h1 class="mb-5">
                    Report
                </h1>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content" aria-expanded="true">
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <table class="table table-bordered datatable" id="datatable" style="z-index: 3;">
                                <thead>
                                <tr role="row" class="bg-primary white">
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">S. No.</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Supplier Name</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Invoice Number</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Delivery Date</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Amount</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Items Delivered</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Submitted By</th>
                                    <th class="border-primary border-darken-1">Image</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="picture_modal" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="picture_modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="picture_modal_title">Picture</h4>

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the script , the jquery functions are not working , when i call the table name or attr in the datatable , it gives error

```
{{--
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>--}}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(function() {
            $('#datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! route('invoice.list') !!}',
                rowId: 'id',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id', name: 'id',class:'id' },
                    { data: 'supplier_name', name: 'supplier_name',class:'supplier_name' },
                    { data: 'invoice_no', name: 'invoice_no', class:'invoice_no'},
                    { data: 'delivery_date', name: 'delivery_date', class:'delivery_date' },
                    { data: 'amount', name: 'amount', class:'amount' },
                    { data: 'items_delivered', name: 'items_delivered', class:'items_delivered' },
                    { data: 'submitted_by', name: 'submitted_by', class:'submitted_by' },
                     { data: 'action', name: 'action', class:'action text-center'},
                ]
            });
        });

        $('#datatable').on('click','.action',function () {
               console.log(1);
         
            $('#picture_modal').modal('show');
         
        });


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the given code is wrong, Please replace these codes,

```
    $('#datatable').on('click','.action',function () {
           console.log(1);
     
        $('#picture_modal').modal('show');
     
    });
```

with this :

```
    $(document).on('click','.action',function () {
           console.log(1);
     
        $('#picture_modal').modal('show');
     
    });
```

Comment: it is due to some problem with the library , when i changed the libraries it gave me the jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: h.ajax is not a function error

Comment: Can you please uncomment bootstrap.min.css and try